# Neural network converges more slowly with htan

Tags: neural-network

I implemented a neural network with sigmoid and hyperbolic tangent activation functions. One thing I have noticed is that sigmoid converges much faster than htan. They both converge and I have checked my code and am confident no coding bugs exist. Are neural networks using sigmoid naturally faster than htan, or might I be doing something wrong?

Comment: _"Are neural networks using sigmoid naturally faster than htan, or might I be doing something wrong?"_ Doesn't that depend on the actual implementation? How should we tell you without seeing the essential implementations?

Comment: Did you normalize your training dataset? If yes, how? Sigmoids works well between 0 and 1 while htan between -1 and 1.

Comment: Also, my neural network uses resilient propagation for its training. My training set is the xor.